# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' Python

Tags: python

so I am currently trying to do a currency converter. Here is the code:

```
Choice = 0
Amount = 0
Converted = 0
Staff = False
print("Welcome to currency converter - Here are your options: ")
print("1. Dollars to sterling")
print("2. Euros to sterling")
print("3. Sterling to dollars")
print("4. Sterling to euros")
Choice=input("Please type the number of your choice")
Amount=input("Enter the amount you would like to convert")
if Choice == "1":
    Amount = Amount * 0.80
elif Choice == "2":
    Amount = Amount * 0.89
print(Amount)
```

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I have tried these solutions:

```
Amount=input(float("Enter the amount you would like to convert"))
```

```
if Choice == "1":
    Amount = Amount * float(0.80)
```

```
if Choice == "1":
    Amount = float(Amount * 0.80)
```

None of these solutions work and I keep getting the same error - I would appreciate it when providing a fix you explain why this error occurs in a basic way - Thanks!

Comment: `float(input(.....))`.  You tried everything except the correct solution

Comment: Your first attempted solution is _almost_ right -- you want `float(input(...))`, not `input(float(...))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

`Amount` is a `str`, not a `float`. You need to make an explicit conversion first.

```
Amount = float(input("..."))
```

or

```
Amount = float(Amount) * 0.80
```

You are applying `float(...)` to just about everything except what it needs to be applied too.